# How to stack ranges horizontally?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

If `{range1; range2; range3}` (I believe this is called embedded arrays) outputs the combined data in a column - top to down, what puts them side by side next to each other?

The 3 ranges may or may not differ in dimensions (different number of columns, which embedded arrays dislike) and I'm trying not to use 3 different formulas in different cells.

Comment: Related [How to append rows from multiple sheets into one “master sheet”?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101681/88163), [How to prepare data to be summarized with a pivot table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58203/88163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- side by side / next to each other: **`{range1, range2, range3}`**
- all in one column stacked under: **`{range1; range2; range3}`**